# Override a single property in a parent project of a application.properties defined in child project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a project, let's call it `BaseProject`, which contains a properties file defining different configurations. One of those properties could be `security.password.minlength=4`.

Now I have a `ProjectA` which builds up on `BaseProject` and there for depends on it.

```
ProjectA
   |
   |--BaseProject
```

Now in `ProjectA` I would like to have a default `security.password.minlength` of 8.

If I  simply add a `application.properties` file to my `ProjectA`, containing `security.password.minlength=8` and the specific property is set to 8. Al tough all the other properties form my `BaseProject` are ignored now, giving me the exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder`

I still would like to use all properties defined in `BaseProject` but solely set the `security.password.minlength` to a different value. How can I achieve this?

**Update**

Currently I let Spring do the handling of the application.properties file. Inside my application, I simply get the values from the Spring environment.

Comment: That will depend on the way the file is consumed (automatically by spring boot, configured in a separate context, completely manual) and whether you can alter both projects, or only the derived Project.

Comment: @ChristianFrommeyer Currently, I let Spring boot do the dirty work. I simple get the values from the loaded environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution for me:

`BaseProject` has a `application.properties` which contains all the default values.

`ProjectA` has a `projectA.properties` which is I integrate with

```
@PropertySource("projectA.properties")
public class ProjectA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ProjectA .class, args);
    }
}
```

This allows me to override any property from the `BaseProject` project in the `projectA.properties` file. The properties which I don't define in `projectA.properties` are still taken from the `application.properties` of the BaseProject`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default property handling of Spring Boot, you can make use of profiles. E.g. you could use a profile named `projecta` for your derived project and specify your properties in a file named `application-projecta.properties`. This will automatically be picked up when you specify the profile to be active (see here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)